# Cannot fetch the value of items in datalist

Tags: javascript, html-datalist

The code is as below:

HTML part:

```
<div style="display:table-cell;" id="page-wrapper" >

<label for="default">Search for GST : </label>
<input type="text" id="default" list="widget_for" placeholder="Type to search for GST">
<datalist id="widget_for" name="widget_for" >
{% for list in opt_list %}
    <option value="{{list.name}}" size="5" > </option>
{% endfor %}

</datalist>    
</div>
```

Script part:

```
function NavigateToSite(){
    var selectedValue = document.getElementById('widget_for').value
    console.log(selectedValue)
}
```

`NavigateToSite()` is called when the button is pressed.

I'm not able to fetch value in variable `selectedValue`. Its returning empty.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should select value of `#default` element instead:

```
function NavigateToSite(){
  var selectedValue = document.getElementById('default').value
  console.log(selectedValue)
}
```